# Info Window With Marker Manager Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow, markerclusterer

I have many map markers with the exact same lat/long cords so no matter how far in I zoom my map still shows the marker cluster and the number of results.

Is there a way to have some onclick or onhover event so that it shows an info box with all of the markers in that cluster in a list?  Then clicking a link within that info box opens up that individual marker info box?

I've read solutions to change the lat, long by a small amount so that they aren't the same location.  I think that is very messy and not that good anyways if there ends up being multiple markers 10+ anyways at the same locationg.  I think it'd be much easier for a user to just click the cluster and bring up the info window with all of those markers in there with links.

Or if someone knows another plugin that does what I am seeking I could work with that too.  I just haven't found much info on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a plug in out there to do what you want, but it's also possible to do without one. I did something like that in one of my projects.

1. Add event listener to each marker; clicking opens marker list info window
2. The content of the marker list info window contains `onclick` attributes that will open the marker info window.

My code was tucked away into functions, but it was basically just this:

```
//1) while creating marker, create click listener that opens the marker list
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    markerWindow.close();
    markerList.open(map, marker);
});

//2) store the content required by the marker's info windows
var markers = [
    [marker1Reference, "The Stadium"],
    [maerker2Reference, "The Supermarket"]
];

//3) the function that is called each time a marker is chosen from the marker list
function openMarkerInfo(markerIndex) {
    markerList.close();
    markerWindow.setContent(markers[markerIndex][1]);
    markerWindow.open(map, markers[markerIndex][0]);
}

//4) info window for the marker list - the content includes JS onclick events that will open each marker info window
markerList = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Choose:<br><br><div href='' class='markerLink' onclick='openMarkerInfo(0)'>The Stadium</div><br><div href='' class='markerLink' onclick='openMarkerInfo(1)'>My House</div>"
});
//5) the marker window that will get set each time a marker is clicked in the list
markerWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

Hope that helps!